# Unix command-line tool for randomly shuffling chunks of bytes in a binary file?

Tags: c, unix, command-line, shuffle

Is there an easy way of shuffling randomly a fixed-size of byte chunks?

I have a large binary file (say, a hundreds of gigabytes) containing many fixed-size of bytes. I do not care about the randomness, but want to shuffle two-byte (or could be any fixed-size of bytes, up to 8) elements in the binary file. Is there a way of combining unix core tools to achieve this goal?  If there is no such tool, I might have to develop a C code.  I want to hear what recommendation people have.

Comment: Shuffling a 100GB file could take a *long* time...

Comment: The Unix command line tools are normally specialized for text files, so your best bet is probably to write a program to do it. As the size is big, you might want to shuffle just a small bit at a time, using memory mapping.

Comment: What is the maximum length of an element? Can it be, for example, 1 megabyte? 1 gigabyte?

Comment: The max could be 4 bytes or 8 bytes.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, feel free to ignore: What do you want to achieve with this shuffling? I just can't imagine a use case where I would need such an operation.

Comment: I generated a binary file with some elements of fixed-size, and only one occurrence of each element. Then, I duplicate this file N times, and this makes each element to occur N times. I need to process them, but want them to be shuffled.

Comment: Well, in that case I think you *should* directly generate the shuffled file. You know quite a lot about it: 1. You know beforehand what chunks can appear, 2. you know that the distribution is flat. This implies that you know the maximal occurence count of a chunk, and that it is a small number (probably fits into a byte). You can directly generate a table of remaining occurence counts using this information, and generate the file from it, decrementing the occurence counts as you go. The mem required for this only depends on the number of possible chunks you use.

Comment: Thank you, coaster, for more input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a stupid shell trick to do so.

1. First, break the file down two 2 byte chunks using `xxd`
2. Shuffle it with `shuf`
3. Reassemble the file using xxd.

eg.

```
xxd -p -c 2 input_file | shuf - | xxd -p -r - output_file
```

I haven't tested it on huge files. You may want to use an intermediary file.

Alternately, you could use `sort -R` like so:

```
xxd -c 2 in_file |sort -R | cut -d' ' -f 2 | xxd -r -p - out_file
```

This depends on `xxd` outputing offsets, which should sort differently for each line.

Comment: Some unixes don't come with `shuf` (My Mac doesn't have it), you can use `perl -MList::Util='shuffle' -e "print shuffle<>"` for portability.

Comment: I have found that I have coreutils (with gshuf) installed in my mac via brew.

Comment: If input_file is too large for this one-liner, you could use split on the beforehand to break it into chunks, run this one-liner on each chunk and then join the chunks afterwards in a random sequence.

Comment: @ronmrdechai: Well, it's a part of GNU coreutils (and `xxd` is apparently a part of vim). You could also replace it with `sort -R`, which might actually be a better idea (as I think it handles large input better. I think `shuf` might try to keep it all in memory.)

Comment: @Hasturkun: GNU coreutils don't come with some unixes (e.g. BSD, OS X). `sort -R` also doesn't work with the BSD coreutils. It can get *really* annoying at times...

Comment: On second thought. don't use `sort -R`. It randomizes the sort keys, but equal values sort equal.

Comment: @ronmrdechai: Oh well. If you end up using perl, you could probably do something more robust (I was really aiming for a stupid shell trick). I'd look at `File::Shuffle`, which uses `Sort::External` for things that won't fit in memory, for example.

Comment: Thank for all of the comments. I am testing Hasturkun's suggestion, and it'd finish a hundreds-mega-byte file within a minute. I will try to use "sort -R" as well since I do not care about randomness. I am testing larger files incrementally, 1G, 10G, hopefully 100G of files.  I will let you know when I have any results.

Comment: 1G-byte file is done within 10 min. I am testing with a 10G-byte file.

Comment: In another machine of mac, 100G-byte file run failed because of lack of memory. I used gshuf command, and I will replace it with 'gsort -R'.

Comment: @SangcheolChoi Any use of standard tools to shuffle a file in the described way will either need to fit the entire file into memory, or be too slow to finish in any adequate amount of time. Of course, you can always relax the problem to make it tractable by splitting the file into blocks. But, if your chunk size it at most 4 bytes, you can easily shuffle arbitrarily large files by first counting occurences of all possible chunks, and then using that information to generate a random file with the same occurence counts (chunk size 3 requires 128 MiB, 32 GiB for 4 byte chunks).

Comment: @cmaster: Well, AFAIK `sort` will use intermediate files as needed. It might still be really slow. A less generic solution would probably be more efficient.

Comment: @cmaster I think that coaster made a good point of relaxing my problem. I generate 100MB file, make 10 copies of 100MB file to create a 1G file. Then, I might just shuffle 1G-btye file, because it seems that 1G-btye file shuffling seems tractable. And, I could repeat this 100 times. Although it is not exactly what I want, but it could essentially solve my current problem. So, for now I do not need to go into developing a C program for shuffling a very large binary file.

Comment: Since Hasturkun's answer is the best at the moment, I mark it as the solution to my problem. Thank you all for answers, and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Given the size of the input files to work with, this is a sufficiently complex problem. I wouldn't try to push the limits of shell scripting, best to code this in C or other.

I'm not aware of a tool that can make this easy.

Comment: +1 The only answer that really takes the constraints into account that were outlined in the question...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
split -b $CHUNK_SIZE $FILE && find . -name "x*" | perl -MList::Util='shuffle' -e "print shuffle<>" | xargs cat > temp.bin
```

This creates a large amount of files each with a file size of `$CHUNK_SIZE` (or less, if the total file size doesn't divide by `$CHUNK_SIZE`), named `xaa`, `xab`, `xac`, etc., lists the files, shuffles the list, and joins them.

This will take up an extra 2 x of disk space and probably won't work with large files.

Comment: The storage overhead is **much** more than 2x, each of the small files will occupy at least one block. How much that is, depends on the filesystem, but it's never less than 512 bytes (+ metadata). With a chunk size of at most 8 bytes (see the question), you have an overhead factor of at least 64. Don't try this with hundreds of Gigabytes!